# Solr Delta Import Scheduling using Apache camel - Invoking Data Import Handler for Delta Import

Tags: solr, apache-camel

I am a newbie to Solr and Camel and this is what I am trying to accomplish:

I am using Data Import Handler to index data into Solr. Everything (Full/Delta import) works fine when I run from the solr admin. I want to write a scheduler that will periodically run and trigger the delta import from my webapp. I am trying to use Apache Camel for this purpose.

My intention is to have Camel Quartz scheduler to create an event every 5 mins and redirect that event to a solr route that will in turn invoke the Solr Delta Import handler.

```
    from("quartz2://SolrUpdateHandlerInvokerTimer?trigger.repeatCount=-1&trigger.repeatInterval=300000")
            .to("direct:insert");

    from("direct:insert")
            .to("solr://localhost:8080/solr/hylighter/dataimport?command=delta-import")
            .to("direct:commit");

    from("direct:commit")
          .setHeader(SolrConstants.OPERATION,constant(SolrConstants.OPERATION_COMMIT))
          .to("solr://localhost:8080/solr/hylighter");
```

But this doesn't work and fails with the following exception.

**Exception:**

```
Caused by: 
org.apache.camel.ResolveEndpointFailedException: Failed to resolve endpoint: solr://localhost:8080/solr/hylighter/dataimport?command=delta-import due to: Failed to resolve endpoint: solr://localhost:8080/solr/hylighter/dataimport?command=delta-import due to: There are 1 parameters that couldn't be set on the endpoint. Check the uri if the parameters are spelt correctly and that they are properties of the endpoint. Unknown parameters=[{command=delta-import}]
```

If I remove `?command=delta-import` the code doesn't throw any exception and runs but when I check dataimport.properties inside my core/conf folder its not updated and neither my index.

Can someone help me identify where I am wrong?

**Edit:**

Route Change:

```
    from("quartz2://SolrUpdateHandlerInvokerTimer?trigger.repeatCount=-1&trigger.repeatInterval=3000")
            .process(new LoggingProcessor())
            .to("direct:insert");

    from("direct:insert")
            .process(new SolrLoggingProcessor())
            .to("solr://localhost:8080/solr/hylighter/dataimport")
            .process(new SolrLoggingProcessor())
            .to("direct:commit");

    from("direct:commit")
            .setHeader(SolrConstants.OPERATION,constant(SolrConstants.OPERATION_COMMIT))
            .process(new CommitLoggingProcessor())
            .to("solr://localhost:8080/solr/hylighter")
            .process(new CommitLoggingProcessor());
```

The trace :

QUARTZ ROUTE: ID-Bee-58722-1390286766821-0-2
From Solr Update Route ID-Bee-58722-1390286766821-0-2
QUARTZ ROUTE: ID-Bee-58722-1390286766821-0-4
From Solr Update Route ID-Bee-58722-1390286766821-0-4
QUARTZ ROUTE: ID-Bee-58722-1390286766821-0-6
From Solr Update Route ID-Bee-58722-1390286766821-0-6
QUARTZ ROUTE: ID-Bee-58722-1390286766821-0-8
From Solr Update Route ID-Bee-58722-1390286766821-0-8

I added a processor before an endpoint in the route and after an endpoint in the route, and I see that once it hits the route which calls the solr data import it doesn't return and move forward in the route.

Comment: Are you using your DIH to index contents of a RDBMS? If so, did you specify the `deltaImportQuery` attributes in your data-config.xml? Could you probably post your data-config?

Comment: Yes I am using DIH to index data from a MySQL database. I have also used a deltaImportQuery. The Delta Import works fine when I am trying to run it from Solr Admin Portal. My problem is I am trying to create a scheduler to run the delta import  periodically using camel which is not working properly.

Comment: Ok, then going through the exception: (1) You do have a folder named `hylighter` in your solr_home and (2) in that folder `hylighter` is a solrconfig.xml? If so (3) in that XML is a `requestHandler` named `/dataimport` which is properly configured? And (4) the there addressed data-config.xml is OK.

Comment: 1.Yes i have the folder hylighter. 2 SolrConfig.xml is present. 3 Request handler /dataimport is configured. 4. data-config.xml is also addressed and is OK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I fixed my problem. I used a Camel-Http Component instead of Camel-Solr Component and invoked the Solr Data Import Handler to do the delta import.

Route:

```
    from("quartz2://SolrUpdateHandlerTimer?trigger.repeatCount=-1&trigger.repeatInterval=300000")
        .to("direct:start");

    from("direct:start")
        .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD, constant("GET"))
        .to("http://localhost:8080/solr/hylighter/dataimport?command=delta-import&commit=true")
        .end();
```